# When making request to GO Gin framework with bad uri, e.g. `/users/%` getting insta 400

Tags: go, go-gin

I have encountered an interesting behavior of GO Gin framework.
E.g. I have an endpoint `GET` which expects an `ID`, e.g. `/users/1`, while this works fine if you pass e.g. `1`, during testing I have noticed that if you send `/users/%` it fails instantly and returns `400 Bad Request` with content type `text/plain; charset=utf-8`.

Now all is ok, but the tricky part is that I want to handle this error with custom error message and I want to receive content type as `application/json; charset=utf-8`. But the problem is that I can't figure out where this request is rejected as in logs I can't see that it was even called and the route looks not called at all.

So my question is, how Gin handles bad uri `query` params like `%` and how it's possible to handle it in my own way?

Comment: % is used to escape some characters in the URL, like spaces, so it's not surprising that a lone % is treated as bad request. In any case, Gin is open source, so you can just download and check for yourself. Alternatively, step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: Exactly, I know that and it all makes sense, no arguments here. But I thought that maybe some one have already encountered this and knows how to solve it :) it would be faster when knowledge is shared but if no one will know, I will need to debug then :(

Comment: try to have a look at this https://cdmana.com/2021/10/20211007100930236X.html

Comment: Ok, I have found who is causing it, thanks @OrYaacov that blog helped to find it, so this is caused by `net/url` func `func unescape(s string, mode encoding) (string, error)`, now I need to find how to work this to return proper content-type

Comment: And this content-type also is returned by `net/http` lib in func `func (*Server).Serve(l net.Listener) error` so does it mean that I cannot change the behavior of `net/http` without rewriting how `Gin` serve the server? As this gin `app.Run` func `func (*gin.Engine).Run(addr ...string) (err error)` is using from `net/http` func `func http.ListenAndServe(addr string, handler http.Handler) error` ?

Comment: Maybe some one has some idea how to bypass it?